# A word for a “troll” who is actually advocating a point of view

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

The word "troll" (in the Internet-related sense) usually means someone who doesn't care about the issues they talk about, but just wants to anger and/or hurt as many people as they can (usually for a perverse sense of power). Now, I have come across many people (online and in person) who have an actual point of view that they are advocating, but who express it in a deliberately abrasive way. Like a troll, they try to hurt and anger people they disagree with, but unlike a troll, they're not trying to hurt anyone they do agree with. Is there a word or term for this?

An example would be a conservative who is trying to hurt, anger, and insult liberals, but not conservatives; or a liberal who is trying to hurt, anger and insult conservatives, but not liberals.

Comment: It sounds like a **politician**.

Comment: I know of no separate word for this in internet parlance, but if you are looking for near-synonyms for *troll,* they include *[etin, thurs,](http://www.gollinkambi.com/beliefs/the_jotuns)* and *[jotun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jotun).*

Comment: It's called a *troll*.

Comment: Did you mean *ADVOCATING* or *AVOCATING*? They are coincidentally words of completely opposite meanings. Advocate = to draw affinity towards. AVOCATE = to shift away from.

Comment: I'm with @HotLicks -- having a POV doesn't mean they're not a troll.  It's like you're trying to say that a sociopath can't take sides, and that's just not true.

Answer (score 5):

The late [Christopher Hitchens](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/16/arts/christopher-hitchens-is-dead-at-62-obituary.html?_r=0) was a primary example of a *gadfly*:

> **2 :** **gadfly**, *n.*: a usually purposely annoying or provoking person; especially :  one who stimulates or provokes to activity and
>   especially to the analysis and defense of ideas by persistent
>   criticism especially of an irritating pointed kind

Or, more formally (as noted in the obituary at the link), a *[polemicist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polemicist)*:

> A person who engages in controversial debate

Answer (score 2):

I think of the word "blowhard." Here is the [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blowhard):

> (derogatory) A person who talks too much or too loudly, especially in a boastful or self-important manner.

There is also "zealot." [Wiktionary Definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zealot):

> One who is zealous, one who is full of zeal for his own specific beliefs or objectives, usually in the negative sense of being too passionate; a fanatic

Or "firebrand." [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firebrand):

> An argumentative troublemaker or revolutionary; one who agitates against the current situation.

Each of the three words I've provided have a negative connotation; they are not compliments.

Answer (score 1):

A ***dogmatist*** is someone who "express[es] personal opinions or beliefs as if they are certainly correct and cannot be doubted" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogmatically)), so that sort of person would by definition be staunchly dismissive of any opposing views.

Comment: Good suggestions. 
I'm looking for something that suggests the deliberate, unrestrained offensiveness, the pleasure in hurting people's feelings, of a "troll," except that they limit their target to the "other side."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **jesuit** (noun) or **jesuitical** (adjective)

> Definition: a person given to subtle and equivocating arguments; a casuist;  a
>   crafty, intriguing person; some one practicing jesuitism, i.e. cunning
>   or deceit, hypocrisy, prevarication, deceptive practices to effect a
>   purpose.

.

> Very early, owing in part to English Protestant propagandists, the
>   word “Jesuitical” came to characterize a form of argument designed
>   less to seek the truth than to make a case, a form of argument that
>   was aggressive and clever but perhaps not always sincere - indeed, one
>   that was at times cunningly equivocal or downright deceitful. Aside
>   from pure anti-Jesuit animus, this nuance probably arose from the work
>   of some 17th-century Jesuit theologians who imperfectly employed a
>   method known as “casuistry” in resolving questions of moral theology -
>   an approach that gave the broadest possible leeway to individual
>   behavior. This form of justification, which became known as “laxism,”
>   may explain why Jesuit priests were the confessors of choice among
>   Europe’s Catholic aristocracy. (*source:dailycon.wordpress.com*)

Answer (score 0):

> polemical

polemical: of, relating to, or involving strongly critical, controversial, or disputatious writing or speech.
"a polemical essay"

Answer (score 0):

[Crusader](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crusader):

> Any vigorous, aggressive movement for the defense or advancement of an idea, cause, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a noun, I'd suggest **provocative** or **abrasive**, with "deliberately" thrown in if you really want to make the point.